# Meaning of the word "take"

Tags: meaning

Just spotted out a line on a cafe's website. May I ask what does the word "take" mean in the following context? It seems that the usual definitions like getting something/ a shot in dictionaries do not fit in this line. Thanks!

"Our menu includes old fashioned favourites as well as modern takes on creative contemporary dishes."

source: http://www.newlondoncafe.co.uk/

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the etymology, but the concept is similar to a "take" when filming a movie.  Each "take" of a given scene may be from a different viewpoint or with slight changes in the script.  The director and film editor would then select the best version.

Answer (score 2):

**take**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/197156?rskey=b3vn3h&result=1#eid)

> 12. An individual's interpretation or assessment of a person, thing, or situation; a particular way of regarding or understanding
>       something. Frequently with on.

Answer (score 0):

See the definition of [take as a noun here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take):

> 1 : a distinct or personal point of view, outlook, or assessment - was asked for her take on recent developments; also : a distinct treatment or variation - a new take on an old style

You can see how this is related to some of the verb meanings, eg:

> 7 a : assume - gods often took the likeness of a human being - when the college took its present form